# In my sql script LEFT JOIN is giving output like CROSS JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table like following

```
DailyData

Date        Id  CompanyName CompanyPrice CompanyId
21-12-2011  123 ABC corp    120           535
25-12-2011  352 Z Edge      101           444
25-12-2011  352 Z Edge      100           444

primary key is `date` and `Id`

ReportData

RId Date        CompanyName TodayPrice CompanyId
1   25-12-2011  Z Edge      230           444

primary key is only `RId`
```

Now I have used following `LEFT JOIN` on both above table like :

```
Select a.date,a.companyname,a.CompanyPrice,b.TodayPrice 
from DailyData a LEFT JOIN ReportData b ON
a.companyid= b.companyid where a.Date = '25-12-2011'
```

But instead of two records it is giving more than two records `(same records multiple times)`

Why is it so ?

Please help me to correct my sql query.

expected output for above data should be:

```
date        companyname companyprice todaysprice
25-12-2011  Z Edge      101           230
25-12-2011  Z Edge      100           230
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current query is missing a JOIN on the actual columns, as a result you are getting a CROSS JOIN result of all the rows that meet the date condition. You will want to use:

```
Select a.date,a.companyname,a.CompanyPrice,b.TodayPrice 
from DailyData a 
LEFT JOIN ReportData b 
  ON a.CompanyId= b.CompanyId
WHERE a.Date = '25-12-2011';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bc6b/3)

Comment: @ashuthinks Can you expand your data in your OP and show what you are getting?  Or create a sql fiddle with some sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Your Join condition: [ `ON a.Date = '25-12-2011'` ] does not establish any condition on table b, therefore, every row in table b is joined to each row in table a with that specified date.

From looking at the two tables it is not obvious whether the they should be joined on date or on CompanyID.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like

```
Select a.date,a.companyname,a.CompanyPrice,b.TodayPrice 
from DailyData a 
LEFT JOIN ReportData b ON 
(b.CompanyId = a.CompanyId )
WHERE a.Date = '25-12-2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bc6b/6/0)

no LEFT and no WHERE clause

```
Select a.date,
  a.companyname,a.CompanyPrice,b.TodayPrice 
from DailyData a 
JOIN ReportData b 
  ON a.CompanyId= b.CompanyId
```